# coldfusion finding a struct in an array

Tags: java, arrays, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have an object that contains an array of structs, the code that generates it loops over a query, takes various values from each row of the query and populates a struct, when the row is done it appends it to an array and the process begins again:

```
<cfscript>
    variables.x = 1;
    variables.aArray = [];
    // loop over my query
    while(variables.x lte variables.qQuery.recordcount){
        variables.stStruct          = {};
        variables.stStruct.nID      = variables.qQuery.id[variables.x];
        variables.stStruct.sText    = variables.qQuery.text[variables.x];

        //etc...

        arrayAppend(variables.aArray,variables.stStruct);
        variables.x++;
    }
    variables.oObject.setArray(variables.aArray);
</cfscript>
```

Later on in my code I want to be able to pull out details about items in that array with only the nID for guidance.  I don't know the array position of that nID which means using a convuluted method of trying to find it.

I had an idea of creating a struct of positions alongside it by altering the above code with.

```
<cfscript>
    variables.x   = 1;
    variables.aArray = [];
    variables.stTracker = {};

    while...yadda
         variables.stStruct = {};
         yadda yadda

         structInsert(variables.stTracker,"variables.qQuery.id[variables.x]","variables.x");
         variables.x++;

    while end

    variables.oObject.setArray(variables.aArray);
    variables.oObject.setTracker(variables.stTracker);
</cfscript>
```

Which would then mean I could do something like `variables.nPosition = structFindKey(variables.oObject.getTracker(),'88')[1].value;`.  This still feels quite inelegant and i'm wondering if I am missing something that makes this a lot easier than what i am doing.

I would be quite happy if there was a solution using java to work this out.

Comment: Does the order in which the items are added to the array matter?

Comment: No, but at the moment they go in much like i have it, however the order of the query comes out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building an array of structures from an existing query I would recommend performing a [Query of Queries](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff9.html). It will allow you to use SQL statements to query your existing result set in memory. This is assuming that all of the data you need is already available in the existing query (sounds like it is from your question).

An example query of query would be:

```
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="qoqexample">  
    SELECT id, text, other_columns 
    FROM variables.qQuery 
    WHERE id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#nID#">
</cfquery>
```

Comment: With this solution I assume you're suggesting I piggy back the query around with me on the object so like `variables.oObject.setQuery(varibles.qQuery)` and then run the QoQ whenever i need to access information from it. It's a solution but not an elegant one if so.

Comment: No I was not suggesting that you add the query to your object. I may not understand the entirety of your code but I was assuming that you could keep your object and query as separate entities; as they currently are. When you need to query the result set, do so from the `variables.qQuery` variable.

Comment: ahh well the query comes from a DAO and within the DAO theres a function that populates the object... so once the object is populated the query doesn't exist anymore, so I would have to populate a setter on the object with the original query for this solution to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Java `LinkedHashMap` which works just like a struct but will maintain the order in which the elements were added. This means you have no need to use an array at all (it's unclear if this will be an issue for you)

You will be able to use all your native `CF` functions on this object just as you would a normal struct.

```
var container = createObject("java", "java.util.LinkedHashMap").init();
for (var x = 1; x <= qQuery.recordCount; x++) {
  container[qQuery['nid'][x]] = qQuery['stext'][x];
}
```

Test for a key as usual:

```
structKeyExists(container, '123');
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

The other option I believe you have considered is a map of the `nid` to the array index position here as `keys`:

```
var keys = {};
var container = [];
for (var x = 1; x <= qQuery.recordCount; x++) {
  var item = {};
  item[qQuery['nid'][x]] = qQuery['stext'][x];

  container[x] = item;
  keys[qQuery['nid'][x]] = x;
}
```

Comment: I suppose maybe i'm trying to do things ass-backwards and could just move it to being a struct of structs which would negate the need for the LinkedHashMap.

Comment: *Re: which would negate the need for the LinkedHashMap* Not quite. Unlike CF structures, LinkedHashMap's have a "predictable iteration order". In a sense, it combines the qualities of an array and a structure. If you need to maintain ordering of the elements, that is a significant difference from the standard CF structures.

Comment: That's true, but for my own needs, since the order does not need to be kept, a LinkedHashMap wouldn't do anything more than a struct of structs. But good advice @Leigh

Comment: @Jareded - (Edit) Ah, okay. I missed the comment mentioning order is not important. In that case, you are right. A structure of structures is simplest. Then you can look-up by id.  With arrays, there is really no other option besides looping to find a match on "id".

Answer (score 1):

CFLib.org looks like it has a likely candidate: [arrayOfStructsFind](http://cflib.org/udf/arrayOfStructsFind)

```
<cfscript>
/**
 * Returns the position of an element in an array of structures.
 * 
 * @param array      Array to search. (Required)
 * @param searchKey      Key to check in the structs. (Required)
 * @param value      Value to search for. (Required)
 * @return Returns the numeric index of a match. 
 * @author Nath Arduini (nathbot@gmail.com) 
 * @version 0, June 11, 2009 
 */
function arrayOfStructsFind(Array, SearchKey, Value){
    var result = 0;
    var i = 1;
    var key = "";
    for (i=1;i lte arrayLen(array);i=i+1){
        for (key in array[i])
        {
            if(array[i][key]==Value and key == SearchKey){
                result = i;
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
</cfscript>
```

So, in your case, you would use it as:

```
ArrayOfStructsFind(variables.oObject.getArray(),"nID","12345")
```